Nginx - Cloudflare ssl handshake failure sslv3
My website is www.maiart.org and I am unable to connect to my website, if I enable proxying on Cloudflare. I have Nginx running on ports 80 and 443, and have installed the Cloudflare origin certifcate. Here is by conf file:
server{
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name www.maiart.org maiart.org;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access_80.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error_80.log;

 root /var/www/maiart;
 location / {
  index index.html;
 }
}

server{
 listen 443 ssl;
 listen [::]:443 ssl;
 server_name www.maiart.org maiart.org;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/access_443.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/error_443.log;

 root /var/www/maiart;
 location / {
  index index.html;
 }
}

Here is my output when  I run  `openssl s_client -connect www.maiart.org:443 -msg
CONNECTED(00000003)
>>> TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 37
>>> TLS 1.3, Handshake [length 0137], ClientHello
    01 00 01 33 03 03 05 e1 85 3c 4d 8d da d6 21 3d
    04 2b f5 96 70 c6 d3 87 44 5e 02 72 d2 f1 d3 7f
    e9 01 71 9d be bb 20 b7 89 19 12 23 a8 4f 1a e1
    be 45 63 9e c4 70 e6 5e d3 58 35 de 1f 26 6a 60
    12 52 ac 03 63 22 4b 00 3e 13 02 13 03 13 01 c0
    2c c0 30 00 9f cc a9 cc a8 cc aa c0 2b c0 2f 00
    9e c0 24 c0 28 00 6b c0 23 c0 27 00 67 c0 0a c0
    14 00 39 c0 09 c0 13 00 33 00 9d 00 9c 00 3d 00
    3c 00 35 00 2f 00 ff 01 00 00 ac 00 00 00 13 00
    11 00 00 0e 77 77 77 2e 6d 61 69 61 72 74 2e 6f
    72 67 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 16 00 14
    00 1d 00 17 00 1e 00 19 00 18 01 00 01 01 01 02
    01 03 01 04 00 23 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 17 00 00
    00 0d 00 2a 00 28 04 03 05 03 06 03 08 07 08 08
    08 09 08 0a 08 0b 08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01 05 01
    06 01 03 03 03 01 03 02 04 02 05 02 06 02 00 2b
    00 05 04 03 04 03 03 00 2d 00 02 01 01 00 33 00
    26 00 24 00 1d 00 20 6a 19 14 8d 83 b4 5c 14 24
    68 17 33 29 16 a5 7c 47 48 53 1f 5f a8 53 67 71
    3d 41 09 90 c5 c5 2b
<<< TLS 1.0, RecordHeader [length 0005]
    15 03 01 00 02
<<< TLS 1.3, Alert [length 0002], fatal handshake_failure
    02 28
4017561AC1760000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1599:SSL alert number 40
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 316 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

If I switch off the proxying by cloudflare, then it works, but obviously the browser shows that it is an insecure site since it can't validate a cloudflare origin certificate. Here are my cloudflare settings:
DNS:

Security level (if I change to full strict, along with proxy, it doesn't work)

Origin server certificate:

Edge certificates and other settings:


You have to edit the question and reveal your Cloudflare settings.

@LexLi Added the cloudflare settings. Let me know if you need me to add anything else, if it helps

First thing I did when I saw the title of this post (sslv3? was Serverfault around in 2002?) was  to scroll down to find out when this was posted. And I scrolled, and I scrolled and I scrolled......then scrolled some more to find it was posted 3 hours ago. Then I scrolled up for a bit to read the question again. OF COURSE SSLV3 doesn't work. That's got nothing to do with the problem here. Which screenshot shows us the certificate and key you deployed to cloudflare? (hint: I don't see this anywhere)

@symcbean that's irrelevant. OpenSSL didn't change its logging from using certain legacy names (like routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3, but people can simply ignore them while reading the rest of the log.

Yes, that is the 2 points I was highlighting in my comment.

The cause is relatively clear now.
Your domain has no active server certificates (should be shown with "Active" under "Status" in the "Edge Certificates" section.
You should chase Cloudflare for solutions,
https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/troubleshooting/general-ssl-errors/#your-cloudflare-universal-ssl-certificate-is-not-active

Thanks a ton! I'll check with them why I haven't received their certificate

I found another post on Cloudflare community with the exact same problem. They suggested to disable and re-enable universal ssl. And it works now! Thanks a lot for your help!
